# Why does the column sitting on top each other?

Tags: flutter

I am pretty new in Dart and I have tried the following:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter App'),
      ),
      body: Column(children: [
        Card(
          child: Text('CHART!!'),
        ),
        Card(child: Text('LIST OF TX'),)
      ],),
    );
  }
}
```

output is:
[image]

Why the children of the column does not be placed next to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `Column` to `Row` if you want them to be next to each others horizontally.

Comment: if you use listview remember use the expand widget to an infinite dimension for the column and row widget.

Answer (score 1):

To place the children next to each other use the Row widget which is very similar to Column. Please see the code below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter App'),
      ),
      body: Row(children: [
        Card(
          child: Text('CHART!!'),
        ),
        Card(child: Text('LIST OF TX'),)
      ],),
    );
  }
}
```